# jquery- info/docs about list of attributes applicable to different types of input elements in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with input elements in a form using jquery...I am trying to obtain the name of a form parameter in a web page, as well as its value (or multiple values in case its something like a drop down box)

I want to do some operations on these form elements... Is there some place you can point me to where a list of attributes available for (and applicable to) different types of form elements is provided? For eg, I need to work with drop down box, list box, radio button, check box, text box and text area. Specifically I require the name of each input element, its value(or set of values) and in case of list box, whether multiple selections can be made within that list box or not.

Update- The jquery 'val' expression retrieves the currently selected value in a radio button/list box etc... I want to obtain all the possible values for input elements that have multiple values as options...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of this stuff is normalized into a single function in jQuery, so you can ask almost any input element for its value and jQuery will give it to you:

http://api.jquery.com/val/

If you wanted to iterate over them and dynamically grab the name and value, it might look something like:

```
var values = {};
$('input, select, textarea', 'form').each(function() {
    values[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: just want to add something to the answer provided by reedlauber- $(this).val() will return all values stored in a radio button / check box..(even if user has selected one value...) However it will return only the value(s) selected by the user in case of drop down box and list box...

Answer (score 1):

The [HTML specification Forms chapter](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html) describes all the different input types. [HTML 5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#forms) will add some new ones, but that is in draft form at present.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will get you started.

```
$('input[type=text]').each(function(){
    console.log('this elements name is '$(this).attr('name') + ' and the value is ' +$(this).val());
});

$('input[type=radio]:checked').each(function(){
    console.log('this elements name is '$(this).attr('name') + ' and the value is ' +$(this).val());
});
```